# Heartbeat 3 binding socket error

Tags: networking, daemon

I've been tying to install Heartbeat3.0.5+Pacemaker1.0.12 on CentOS 6.3 64bit via yum. The installation seems to be successful, but there is a problem when starting Heartbeat.

I put some info related to this issue below.

Node Info

```
Active  : hm5
Standby : hm6
```

Package Info

```
[root@hm5 rpm]# rpm -qa | grep -i heartbeat
heartbeat-libs-3.0.5-1.1.el6.x86_64
heartbeat-3.0.5-1.1.el6.x86_64

[root@hm5 rpm]# rpm -qa | grep -i pacemaker
pacemaker-1.0.11-1.2.el6.x86_64
pacemaker-libs-1.0.11-1.2.el6.x86_64
```

ha.cf Info

```
[root@hm5 rpm]# cat /etc/ha.d/ha.cf 
pacemaker on
logfacility local1

debug 1
udpport 694

keepalive 2
warntime 20
deadtime 24
initdead 48

bcast eth1

node hm5
node hm6
watchdog /dev/watchdog
```

Interface Info

```
[hm5]
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:52:00:18:DE:97  
          inet addr:192.168.122.35  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:121033 (118.1 KiB)  TX bytes:58678 (57.3 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:52:00:6F:E3:74  
          inet addr:192.168.123.5  Bcast:192.168.123.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:68171 (66.5 KiB)  TX bytes:126 (126.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

[hm6]
[root@hm6 ~]# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:52:00:40:7D:BE  
          inet addr:192.168.122.36  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:77115 (75.3 KiB)  TX bytes:6223 (6.0 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:52:00:72:DB:F1  
          inet addr:192.168.123.6  Bcast:192.168.123.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:70729 (69.0 KiB)  TX bytes:126 (126.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Error Log After Starting Heartbeat by Root User

```
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(udpport,694)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(keepalive,2)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(warntime,20)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(deadtime,24)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(initdead,48)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(bcast,eth1)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(node,hm5)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(node,hm6)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(watchdog,/dev/watchdog)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: uid+hacluster, gid+<null>
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: uid+hacluster, gid+<null>
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: uid+<null>, gid+haclient
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: uid+root, gid+<null>
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: uid+<null>, gid+haclient
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: Beginning authentication parsing
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: 16 max authentication methods
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: Keyfile opened
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: Keyfile perms OK
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: 16 max authentication methods
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: Found authentication method [sha1]
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: info: AUTH: i+1: key + 0x215bf40, auth+0x7fdb7ac89db0, authname+sha1
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: Outbound signing method is 1
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: Authentication parsing complete [1]
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(cluster,linux-ha)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(hopfudge,1)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(baud,19200)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(auto_failback,legacy)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(hbgenmethod,file)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(realtime,true)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(msgfmt,classic)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(conn_logd_time,60)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(log_badpack,true)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(syslogmsgfmt,true)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(coredumps,true)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(autojoin,none)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(uuidfrom,file)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(compression,zlib)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(compression_threshold,2)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(traditional_compression,no)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(max_rexmit_delay,250)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: Setting max_rexmit_delay to 250 ms
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(record_config_changes,on)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(record_pengine_inputs,on)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(enable_config_writes,on)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: add_option(memreserve,6500)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: WARN: Logging daemon is disabled --enabling logging daemon is recommended
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: info: **************************
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: info: Configuration validated. Starting heartbeat 3.0.5
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: debug: HA configuration OK.  Heartbeat starting.
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1448]: info: Heartbeat Hg Version: node: 7e3a82377fa8c88b4d9ee47e29020d4531f4629a
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: info: heartbeat: version 3.0.5
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: info: Heartbeat generation: 1343634035
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: debug: uuid is:8724b422-87c2-4056-9433-7be507f2efb3
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: debug: FIFO process pid: 1452
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: debug: opening bcast eth1 (UDP/IP broadcast)
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: debug: glib: SO_BINDTODEVICE(r) set for device eth1
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1452]: debug: pid 1452 locked in memory.
Jul 30 19:12:52 hm5 heartbeat: [1452]: debug: Limiting CPU: 6 CPU seconds every 60000 milliseconds
Jul 30 19:12:53 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:12:54 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:12:55 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:12:56 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:12:57 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:12:58 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:12:59 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:13:00 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:13:01 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:13:02 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Unable to bind socket (Permission denied). Giving up.
Jul 30 19:13:02 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: info: glib: UDP Broadcast heartbeat closed on port 694 interface eth1 - Status: 1
Jul 30 19:13:02 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: make_io_childpair: cannot open bcast eth1
Jul 30 19:13:02 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: debug: Exiting from pid 1449 [rc+4]
Jul 30 19:13:03 hm5 heartbeat: [1452]: CRIT: Emergency Shutdown: Master Control process died.
Jul 30 19:13:03 hm5 heartbeat: [1452]: CRIT: Killing pid 1449 with SIGTERM
Jul 30 19:13:03 hm5 heartbeat: [1452]: CRIT: Emergency Shutdown(MCP dead): Killing ourselves.
Jul 30 19:13:03 hm5 heartbeat: [1452]: debug: Process 1452 processing SIGTERM
Jul 30 19:13:03 hm5 heartbeat: [1452]: debug: Exiting from pid 1452 [rc+15]
```

The main problem seems to be related to

```
Jul 30 19:13:01 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: ERROR: glib: Error binding socket (Permission denied). Retrying.
Jul 30 19:13:02 hm5 heartbeat: [1449]: info: glib: UDP Broadcast heartbeat closed on port 694 interface eth1 - Status: 1
```

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled? If so have you tried disabling it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's try anyway, with information you provided my bet is you hit a SELinux policy problem.

How to check if SELinux is enabled?

```
[root@ragnarok ~]# getenforce  
Enforcing
```

If the command returns enforcing, your system is running with SELinux enabled, if that's the case, let's try to put it on Permissive mode and see if your problem goes away.

How to change SELinux mode to Permissive?

```
[root@ragnarok ~]# setenforce 0
[root@ragnarok ~]# getenforce 
Permissive
```

That'll work till you reboot, so now it's time to try to start your failing service.

If we're lucky and that did the trick, you might be hitting the following bug/errata:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=809746

You could check with commands provided by the bug reporter and see if the results are the same. If that'd be the case, it seems it's been fixed upstream since June and you might need to update your system or wait until CentOS applies the fix.

Please, get back to us with your findings.

Comment: The issue was about SELinux, after disabling this, things just went well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually when you think you have everything properly configured and anything is not working, SELinux is a good starting point. Glad it's working. Please remember to accept and value the answer so others can make use of it :-). Thanks.